# Javascript not recognising function

Tags: javascript, typeerror

(This is my first javascript project, so the solution may be obvious to more experienced people, but it's not to me!)

I am trying to code the input from three drop down lists. The context is helping people assess whether they meet the criteria for disability assistance.

- The first drop-down asks whether a person can stand at all or not
  (yes/no)
- The next asks how far they can walk (choose from a range of
  distances
- The third asks whether they need any aids or adaptations
  (no/yes)

Depending on how far they can walk they get a score: 12 is the maximum. However if a person can't stand they automatically get 12 points. also, depending on whether they need any aids and adaptations can affect the scoring.

The intention is therefore to have an if-then-else function (if to respond to person unable to stand, else if to create output dependent on walking distance and need for adaptations, and else to create output based purely on walking distance.

Everything works fine if until i include the adaptations drop down. the problem is that to do this i need to create a variable based on the value returned from the 'distance walked' function. at this point the console returns 'Uncaught TypeError: getdistancescore is not a function'.the coding has no problem recognising getdistancescore until i do this
here's the coding: (the line that causes the problems is marked "//this is the problem"

```
  //stand-yes-no
var standYN =[];
 standYN["mp1"]=0;
 standYN["mp2"]=1;

  function getstandYN(){
var standscore=0;
var theForm = document.forms["mobilityform"];
var standscore = theForm.elements["mobp1"];
getstandYN =  standYN[standscore.value];
return getstandYN;
}   
  //end standyes-no


 //distances
   var distances = [];
distances["mp3"]=0;
distances["mp4"]=4;
distances["mp5"]=8;
distances["mp6"]=12;
distances["mp7"]=12;
//note mp5 could be 10


function getdistancescore(){
var distancescore=0;
var theForm = document.forms["mobilityform"];
var distancescore = theForm.elements["mobp2"];
getdistancescore =  distances[distancescore.value];
return getdistancescore;
}
  //end distances



  //needs aid or appliance yes-no
var aiappYN =[];
     aiappYN["mp1"]=0;
     aiappYN["mp2"]=1;

  function getaiappYN(){
var aiappscore=0;
var theForm = document.forms["mobilityform"];
var aiappscore = theForm.elements["mobp3"];
getaiappYN =  aiappYN[aiappscore.value];
return getaiappYN;
}   
  //end needs aids or appliance yes-no



  //CALCULATION STARTS
  var ai_appscore = getaiappYN()
  var standingscore = getstandYN();


  //THIS IS THE PROBLEM
  var walkingdistance = getdistancescore();
  //END THIS IS THE PROBLEM

  if (standingscore == 1){
var actualscore = 12
  }

  //extra 'else if' to go here       

  else  {
var actualscore = getdistancescore();
  }
  //CALCULATION ENDS

  //display results
var divobj = document.getElementById("score");
divobj.innerHTML="Total Score "+actualscore;


var divobj = document.getElementById("check");
divobj.innerHTML="Check "+standingscore;
}
```

Apologies if i haven't explained this very well, and for the length of the question. I've searched on a wide range of help sites but can't find anything that explains what's happening

Answer (score 2):

Do you see what you're doing with `getstandYN` here ?

```
function getstandYN(){
  var standscore=0;
  var theForm = document.forms["mobilityform"];
  var standscore = theForm.elements["mobp1"];
  getstandYN =  standYN[standscore.value];
  return getstandYN;
}
```

`getstandYN` is a function, then in the middle of the function you reassign it to `standYN[standsore.value]`

Notice what happens here

```
function foo() {
  foo = 5;
  return foo;
}

foo();            // 5
foo();            // Uncaught TypeError: foo is not a function
console.log(foo); // "5"
```

Comment: Doh! amended my coding accordingly and problem resolved. Thanks very much, especially for explaining so clearly something that must be obvious to you!